# how to set attribute to jquery tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-tabs

I am making dynamically jquery tabs and I want to assign the attribute `onclick` to each tab.

```
$(function() {
var index = 0;
$("#addTab").live('click', function() {
    index++;
    var title = 'Tab.....  ' + index;
    var url = '#fragment-' + index;

   $('#tabs').tabs("add", url, title, [index]);
   $('li.ui-state-default').attr("onclick","a();"); // this line


});
```

but this is not working..

JS Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ranasaani/gP3YZ/18/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use the builtin select event of the tab :
http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#event-select

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
    select: function() {
        // your code;
    }
});
```

Working exemple : http://jsfiddle.net/cCN6H/

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to add it directly to the tab ? 
You're using JQuery you can handle the click event like this :

```
$('yourtabselector').click(function(){})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#addTab li.ui-state-default').live('click', function(){

    a();//do something

});
```